# javascript: a = b. Is it possible to change a but not influence b?

Tags: javascript

Javascript Question. I am pretty new to javascript so pardon me if anything is not clear.

Please play following example at (right click) "inspect --> Console".

Example:

```
o = [1,2,3];
y = o;
delete y[0];
y;// result: [undefined × 1, 2, 3]
o;// result: [undefined × 1, 2, 3]
```

Is it possible that the delete of `y` does not affect `o`? Here I made `y` equal to `o`. I just wanted to delete the first item of `y` but not `o`. However, `o` changes with `y` together. I wonder if it is possible to prevent `o` being changed even I change `y`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
y = o.slice()
```

Then that'll give you your own copy.

You can even use:

```
y = [...o]
```

depending on the browser support.